# Swift Google Maps GMS Marker not sticking on user location

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an issue with my `GMSMarker`, it seems that it does not stick on user location.  I want to stick the marker to user location itself, check my code below.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    UpdateService.instance.updateUserLocation(withCoordinate: position.target)
    UpdateService.instance.updateContractorLocation(withCoordinate: position.target)
}

func loadContractorAnnotation() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        DataService.instance.REF_CONTRACTOR.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let contractorSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for contractor in contractorSnapshot {
                    if contractor.hasChild("coordinate") {
                        if contractor.childSnapshot(forPath: "contractorIsAvailable").value as? Bool == true {
                            if let contractorCoordinateDict = contractor.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                                let coordinateArray  = contractorCoordinateDict["coordinate"] as! NSArray
                                let contractorCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinateArray[0] as! CLLocationDegrees , longitude: coordinateArray[1] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                                CATransaction.begin()
                                CAAnimation.init().duration = 0.5
                                self.contractorMarker.position = contractorCoordinate
                                self.contractorMarker.iconView = self.markerImageView(image: UIImage(named: "contractor-marker")!, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
                                self.contractorMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                                CATransaction.commit()
                                self.contractorMarker.map = self.mapView
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }) 
    }
}
// ViewDidLoad()
DataService.instance.REF_CONTRACTOR.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        self.loadContractorAnnotation()
})
```

And it looks like whenever I drag my map it seems that it will follow the icon centered in my google map instead it will stick only on user location when i drag the google map.  You can check it on this [video](https://youtu.be/SY2mATUQclM) that I upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, It seems that I put everything on google map,

I moved the lines of code below from `didChange position` function.

```
UpdateService.instance.updateUserLocation(withCoordinate: position.target)
UpdateService.instance.updateContractorLocation(withCoordinate: position.target)
```

into this block of code.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```